# What is dropship and special order and how they differ

Tags: netsuite

what is drop-ship and special order in netsuite and how they differ ? I am very  confused about these and wants to understand them clearly.

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two links to help you out

[NetSuite special orders](https://softwareselect.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/working-with-special-orders-in-netsuite/)

The link below is from Wikipedia and not NetSuite specific, but the first paragraph describes this well enough:
[Drop-ship orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shipping)

NetSuite describes their Drop-ship functionality as follows:

> ### Drop-ship/Endless aisle.
>
> An end-to-end, automated
>   drop-ship fulfillment process provides the capabilities
>   to expand your assortment without increasing
>   warehouse and store footprints. Efficiently manage
>   drop-ship programs, including order capture and
>   validation, communicating drop-ship orders to
>   suppliers, receipt of supplier acknowledgement and
>   shipping confirmations, seamless communications
>   back to the customer and settlement with
>   the supplier.

Comment: Pleasure. Are you unsure about the difference between the two terms in theory or the difference in regards to NetSuite and how NetSuite deals with both?

Comment: From my own understanding, special orders are used when you sell a product that you do not keep in stock, perhaps the item is only ordered once in a while and it isn't worth keeping it in stock. Say you sell pens and everyone only ever buys blue pens. Then one customer orders a red pen. You will create a special order for this. When creating a special order on NetSuite, NetSuite automatically creates a PO for that item, related to the relevant producer - since the item will not already be in your own inventory.

Comment: Drop ship orders refer to orders that will not follow your regular supply chain. Lets say you own a chain store and normally when an order comes in - you sell directly from the shop floor. When a client places an order for a red pen and you do not ever keep the stock at your store, you pass the SO on to the producer or another chain store, which will then ship this order to the client directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are scenarios when you dont want to keep certain item in stock (may be because they are expensive and the company don't want to block funds and customers order them once in a while). 
So you create Drop Ship Item which are sent directly do customers from Prefrred Vendor

Special Order Item a.k.a Just in time are special/Customized Item. Eg: A pen with your name on it, etc.

On both the Item types you specify the Preferred Vendor. Moment you create transaction with DropShip/SpecialOrder items; corresponding PO is automatically created.